# Counting building polygons in neighborhood polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I have two layers, one of them is neighborhood data and the other is the buildings in the city. I want to count the buildings in a neighborhood (by using borders) and add this value to the neighborhood table as a field. How can I do this in ArcMap?

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use a spatial join. The easiest way to do this is (IMO) is by right-clicking the neighborhood (polygon) layer and selecting Joins and Relates -> Join and then at the top (where it says "what do you want to join to this layer") change from tabular join to a spatial join (based on spatial location). Select your point layer. Then you have options for statistics you want for any numeric fields in your point layer but you always get a COUNT field added in your output which is what you wanted. Hope that helps.

You can also do this using the spatial join tool in the Overlay Toolbox within Analysis tools.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can accomplish this by right-clicking on the neighborhood layer, choosing 'Joins and Relates', choosing 'Join', and in the Join Data box that pops up, choose 'Join data from another layer based on spatial location', select your buildings layer and then select 'Sum' as the attribute you want added as a numeric attribute.

See also: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000034000000

EDIT: You might run into some issues with building polygons that lie on a boundary (if they lie on a boundary which neighborhood do they belong to?), so you might consider first creating a layer of building centroids and then using the building_centroids layer instead of the buildings layer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using a model that, in your case, would iterate over each neighborhood and select then count all of the buildings whose centroid is within that neighborhood. This is pretty straightforward, I can post an image of the model that I use if you want.

Also, you could adapt this from [ESRI Support](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30779):

Summary Instructions provided describe how to count the number of point features that are contained in a polygon.

Procedure

```
Create a count field and a spatial join between the point shapefile and the polygon shapefile.

In the attribute table of the point shapefile, create a field called 'Count' of type 'Short Integer'.

Calculate the Count field equal to 1 by right-clicking on the field name > Field Calculator > Enter a 1 in the white dialog area below "Count = ", and click OK.

Right-click the polygon shapefile and click Joins and Relates > Joins. Click the dropdown list and select 'Join data from another layer based on spatial location'.

Specify the point shapefile from Step 1.

Select the first bullet, each polygon is given a summary of the numeric attributes, for Step 2, and check the 'Sum' box.

At Step 3, specify an output location and click OK.

A polygon shapefile with the 'Count' field indicating how many point features lie within each polygon feature is now present.
```